# Sort "All Sites" by user's use.

Tags: feature-request, usability

Hello;

In the StackExchange button on the top bar one of the options says "all sites" in which all of stackexchange's sites are listed. I think they should also be sorted by user preference.

Such preference could be calculated automatically by the site based on many aspects, starting with the user's rating on each or the user's amount of time lately spent on each perhaps. It could even be set by the user himself.

Comment: Isn't this a better question for meta.stackoverflow since it pertains to all of the sites, not just this site?

Comment: @CharlesBoyung, asking questions on a child meta is perfectly fine.  Things can either be handled by the community, or vetted.  If there is support for it, then there could be a post on MSO, but it isn't always necessary.

Comment: Thank @Rebecca. You folks have been very responsive to meta.ux questions. Much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list is sorted - in the following ways:

- For accounts where you have >200 reputation, the sites will be listed in descending order based on your reputation.
- For accounts <200 reputation, the remaining sites will be listed in random order.

Comment: Thank you :). Is that documented anywhere?